# Which Excel function is best suited to create an autofill-ing list of variable combinations by inputting min/max for each (3 variables)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Which function can I use/learn, if any, to create a self-filling table where I enter in the min max variable for 3 inputs, and get a list with every combination of those 3 inputs?

AKA

```
Variable N = Min 1, Max 100
Variable M = Min 10, Max 50
Variable P = Min 1, Max 365

List:
N1, M10, P1
N1, M10, P2
N1, M10, P3
....
N1, M11, P1
N1, M11, P2
N1, M11, P3
.....
N2, M10, P1
N2, M10, P2
N2, M10, P3
...
N100, M50, P363
N100, M50, P364
N100, M50, P365
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you, is that improved or still confusing?

Comment: I'm sorry @NaturallyNick, but your problem can't be solved with Excel (or other spreadsheet processor) yet. Today's table standard suggests that you won't need more than 1,048,576 rows. And to solve your example, you need 100 * 41 * 365 = 1496500 rows, that is, a little more.

Comment: This is far better solved using something like Python or another programming/scripting language that supports nested `for` loops. Programming questions would be off topic here and belong at [so]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind not being able to put the data in a workbook (say, if you want to use it solely in a PowerPivot data model, or in a pivot table), then you can do this:

Use Data>Get & Transform Data>Get Data>From other sources>Blank Query>

When the Power Query Editor opens, click 'Advaned Editor' on the home tab.

Replace the contents of the Advanced Editor with this query:

```
let
    listN = List.Numbers(1,100),
    #"Convert listN to a table" = Table.FromList(listN, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    listM = List.Numbers(10,41),
    #"convert listM to a table" = Table.FromList(listM, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    listP = List.Numbers(1,365),
    #"convert listP to a table" = Table.FromList(listP, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Rename Column1 from tableP to P" = Table.RenameColumns(#"convert listP to a table",{{"Column1", "P"}}),
    #"Change P to integer data type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Rename Column1 from tableP to P",{{"P", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Add tableM as a column called M" = Table.AddColumn(#"Change P to integer data type", "M", each #"convert listM to a table"),
    #"Expanded M" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Add tableM as a column called M", "M", {"Column1"}, {"Column1"}),
    #"Rename Column1 from tableM to M" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Expanded M",{{"Column1", "M"}}),
    #"Change M to integer data type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Rename Column1 from tableM to M",{{"M", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Add tableN as a column called N" = Table.AddColumn(#"Change M to integer data type", "N", each #"Convert listN to a table"),
    #"Expanded N" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Add tableN as a column called N", "N", {"Column1"}, {"Column1"}),
    #"Rename Column1 from tableN to N" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Expanded N",{{"Column1", "N"}}),
    #"Change N to integer data type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Rename Column1 from tableN to N",{{"N", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Change N to integer data type"
```

This will create the three lists and then perform the cross-join between them.

You can then use Home>Close & Load To> and select 'Only create connection' and 'Add this data to the Data Model'.

Again, this will not put the results of the query in the workbook because, as another commenter pointed out, there are too many rows in the result. If you're not used to working with DAX, this may prove a non-starter.

If it will suffice to create only the lists (and not do the join), then you can put these formulas in different columns:

```
=SEQUENCE(100)
=SEQUENCE(41,1,10)
=SEQUENCE(365)
```

All in all, if you are planning on doing this kind of join and don't have the appropriate programming background, my recommendation is that you start by creating three one-column tables in a database (SQL Server, MySQL, whatever really), one for each of the lists you want to join, and using a simple:

```
create table three_lists
as
select *
from tableN, tableM,  tableP;
```

Comment: Thank you! It's really impressive since it's such a clean solution. I think you're right in that it's a bit over my head for now, but it's great to have an idea of what to start researching.